# how to mimic `--numeric-owner` in tarfile?

Tags: python-3.x, tar, tarfile

with tar command we can use `tar --numeric-owner -cf - test | tee` to make sure in tar data it use number to represent owner:group. How can we do this in python3's tarfile? It seems only extract mentioned numeric owner.

Comment: related cpython issue: https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/67382

Comment: The `extract` and [`extract_all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tarfile.html#tarfile.TarFile.extractall) functions do support `numeric_owner`, but `add` does not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've faced a similar problem. After some investigation the only solution I was able to come up with was to pass a TarInfo filter when adding the files to the tarball. Something like:

```
def tar_filter(tarinfo: TarInfo) -> TarInfo:
    # tar filter to mimic --numeric-owner argument
    tarinfo.uname = ''
    tarinfo.gname = ''
    return tarinfo

with tarfile.open(<tar_file_name>, w:gz) as tar:
    tar.add(<file_to_add>, filter=tar_filter)
```